# MFC dialog with System.Window.Forms.Form shows new dialog, Control.Visible.set(bool value) is called on it and it freezes

Tags: winforms, mfc, modal-dialog, freeze

[image: Windows.Forms.Form + MFC CDialog freeze]

In our application we call DoModal() on a dialog inherited from MFC CDialog, in this modal dialog we show some 3rd party content which uses System.Windows.Forms and this content creates new System.Windows.Forms.Form and when it calls ShowDialog() on the Form, the new dialog is shown all white and freezes. The new dialog hangs in _NtWaitForSingleObject and I don't know why and what to do.

Callstack from ShowDialog() in our application (freezing):

```
ntdll.dll!_NtWaitForSingleObject@12()  + 0x15 bytes 
KernelBase.dll!_WaitForSingleObjectEx@12()  + 0x98 bytes    
kernel32.dll!_WaitForSingleObjectExImplementation@12()  + 0x43 bytes    
user32.dll!_InternalCallWinProc@20()  + 0x23 bytes  
user32.dll!_UserCallWinProcCheckWow@32()  + 0xb7 bytes  
user32.dll!_DispatchClientMessage@24()  + 0x51 bytes    
user32.dll!___fnDWORDOPTINLPMSG@4()  + 0x35 bytes   
ntdll.dll!_KiUserCallbackDispatcher@12()  + 0x2e bytes  
user32.dll!_NtUserMessageCall@28()  + 0x15 bytes    
user32.dll!_SendMessageWorker@24()  + 0x8c15 bytes  
user32.dll!_SendMessageW@16()  + 0x4c bytes 
user32.dll!_xxxRemoveDefaultButton@16()  + 0x56 bytes   
user32.dll!_xxxSaveDlgFocus@8()  + 0x4a bytes   
user32.dll!_DefDlgProcWorker@24()  + 0x196d bytes   
user32.dll!_DefDlgProcW@16()  + 0x29 bytes  
user32.dll!_InternalCallWinProc@20()  + 0x23 bytes  
user32.dll!_UserCallWinProcCheckWow@32()  + 0xb7 bytes  
user32.dll!_CallWindowProcAorW@24()  + 0x5e bytes   
user32.dll!_CallWindowProcW@20()  + 0x1b bytes  
mfc100u.dll!CWnd::DefWindowProcW()  + 0x44 bytes    
mfc100u.dll!CWnd::WindowProc()  + 0x3b bytes    
mfc100u.dll!AfxCallWndProc()  + 0xb5 bytes  
mfc100u.dll!AfxWndProc()  + 0x37 bytes  
mfc100u.dll!AfxWndProcBase()  + 0x56 bytes  
user32.dll!_InternalCallWinProc@20()  + 0x23 bytes  
user32.dll!_UserCallWinProcCheckWow@32()  + 0xb7 bytes  
user32.dll!_DispatchClientMessage@24()  + 0x51 bytes    
user32.dll!___fnDWORD@4()  + 0x2b bytes 
ntdll.dll!_KiUserCallbackDispatcher@12()  + 0x2e bytes  
user32.dll!_NtUserShowWindow@8()  + 0x15 bytes  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetVisibleCore(bool value = true) + 0x402 bytes   
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore(bool value = true) + 0x88 bytes   
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.Visible.set(bool value) + 0x16 bytes  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(int reason = 4, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context = {System.Windows.Forms.Application.ModalApplicationContext}) + 0x1a2 bytes 
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) + 0x4c bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(System.Windows.Forms.Form form) + 0x33 bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window owner) + 0x329 bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog() + 0xc bytes
```

Callstack from ShowDialog() in dedicated application (not freezing):

```
[Managed to Native Transition]  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(System.IntPtr dwComponentID, int reason = 4, int pvLoopData = 0) + 0x577 bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(int reason = 4, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context = {System.Windows.Forms.Application.ModalApplicationContext}) + 0x1bc bytes 
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) + 0x55 bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window owner) + 0x432 bytes
```

So in the freezing situation, Control.Visible.set(bool value) is called and in the non freezing situation, ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(System.IntPtr dwComponentID, int reason = 4, int pvLoopData = 0) is called. Why?

I tried to search and found out that people had similar freeze problem and fixed it with using attribute [STAThread] or SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA), but I am not sure if this is the same situation and the main application is in C++, not C#. All those dialog creations occur in our Main Thread which is created with CWinAppEx::Run().

What happens and how can I fix the freezing correctly and elegantly?